# Bacula and send file list to RunAfterJob script

Tags: backup, bash, scripting, bacula, diff

I have Bacula backup server. And I run sripts before and after backuping, using RunBeforeJob and RunAfterJob.
Can I send to script in "RunAfterJob" parameter contained list of backuped files?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can send a jobid `%j` and then run `echo "list files jobid=foo" | bconsole`.